# Error: Invalid value when querying a date type field using sequelize^6.27.0 Error: Invalid value

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am working on an express project, I use the ORM sequelize for the data persistence of my schemas with Mysql 8.0. I am trying to perform a simple DELETE query in which I query the field "Indicator_Name" and two date ranges between 2020-05-25 and 2022-12-19 my schema and query is as follows:

```js
const deleteRecordsBetweenDates = async () =>{
    let startDate = new Date("2020-05-25").toJSON().slice(0, 10);
    let finalDate = new Date("2022-12-19").toJSON().slice(0, 10);
    const deleteRecords = await indcds_scheme.destroy({
        where: {
            [Op.and]: [
                {"Nombre_indicador": "Covid 19"}, 
                {[Op.between] : [
                    {Fecha_de_inicio: "2020-05-25"}, 
                    {Fecha_de_inicio: "2022-12-19"}
                ]}
            ]
        } 
    });
    return deleteRecords;
}

   router.delete("/delete", async (req, res) => {
    deleteRecordsBetweenDates()
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
        return res.sendStatus(200)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
        return res.sendStatus(500)
      });
  });
```

Scheme:

```js
const indcds_scheme = connection.define(
  "indicador_categoría",
  {
    Id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    Nombre_indicador: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
    Descripción_indicador: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
    Valor_de_variable: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    Última_actualización: Sequelize.DATE,
    Fecha_de_inicio: Sequelize.DATEONLY,
    Población_rural: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    Población_urbana: Sequelize.INTEGER,
 },
 {
   freezeTableName: true,
 }
);
```

I followed this question: [https://stackoverflow-com.translate.goog/questions/46390150/sequelize-not-accepting-valid-moment-js-object-in-where-clause/46390179?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=es&_x_tr_hl=es-419#46390179](https://stackoverflow.com)

to convert dates to valid mysql date formats, but still having the same problem:

```js
 let startDate = new Date("2020-05-25").toJSON().slice(0, 10);
```

[image]

Comment: Show us the generated SQL.  Shouldn't `toJSON` be `toString`?  But why do any converting?  `"2020-05-25"` is already a string that can be compared to a `DATE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue could be with the way you are using Sequelize's query options for date ranges or the JSON conversion.
I think the use of Op.and to combine conditions is unnecessary in this case. Because sequelize implicitly treats multiple keys within the where object as an AND operation anyway. So you can directly use an array of conditions without explicitly using Op.and. Also the usage of Op.between could be adjusted to include the correct date range. Instead of specifying an array of two objects inside [Op.between], you could provide an array of two dates representing the start and end dates. Something like this,

```
const startDate = new Date("2020-05-25")
const finalDate = new Date("2022-12-19")

const deleteRecords = await indcds_scheme.destroy({
  where: {
    Nombre_indicador: "Covid 19",
    Fecha_de_inicio: {
      [Op.between]: [startDate, finalDate],
    }
  }
})
```

Also, you don't need to convert the dates to JSON format. If I am not wrong, I beleive Sequelize handles date objects correctly. If this doesn't work, you can try using Op.gte and Op.lte instead.

```
where: {
     Nombre_indicador: "Covid 19",
     Fecha_de_inicio: {
       [Op.gte]: startDate,
       [Op.lte]: finalDate,
     },
   }
```